# CSS not getting applied to <label>

Tags: html, css

I am developing a form and setting a size for the label and aligning it right so as to look decent. However the CSS is not getting applied. Here is my code:

```
label{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/)

How do I get this working?

Comment: it is working mate => http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/2/ ...you have problem in your layout, change the DOM :)

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try (i test in your fiddle)

```
display:inline-block;
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/5/)

Comment: Can you tell me why do we need to use this?

Comment: by default some html element have default css value like p have margin-top and margin-bottom or body have margin:20px so label have display:inline, you can set width for dispaly inline because it's inline

Comment: One follow up question: How do I get the button at the center? `margin: 0 auto;` isnt working. http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/8/

Comment: i update your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/9/ when you don't set width for element or use float margin:0 auto not work better use <center> tag or set text-align:center for parent DIV

Comment: I am notusing `<center>` tag because it is not recommended. Anyways `margin-left: 50%;` solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @RahulDesai : no don't use <center> tag. Use like this http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/10/ . put your button inside the div and align it to center

Comment: no no no that's not center your element use text-align:center to parent tag, that's not cross browser

Answer (score 2):

You could make it an `inline-block` element:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xJTH6/)

```
label{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

You need to do this because a `label` is an `inline` element, and the following applies to it:

> [**10 Visual formatting model details - 10.2 Content width: the 'width' property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property)
>
> This [width] property does not apply to non-replaced inline elements. The content width of a non-replaced inline element's boxes is that of the rendered content within them (before any relative offset of children). Recall that inline boxes flow into line boxes. The width of line boxes is given by the their containing block, but may be shorted by the presence of floats

Answer (score 1):

add `display:inline-block` in your `label` [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/3/)

Answer (score 1):

LIke this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/4/)**

**css**

```
label{
    width:50%;
    text-align: right;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/7/

change the css code like this

```
body{
    font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
/*changes here*/
#book_tickets label{
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```